# What does ‘so’ indicate, and what’s the part of speech of it?

Tags: parts-of-speech

> It was the fifteenth of January, about nine o’clock in the morning: Bessie was gone down to breakfast; my cousins had not yet been summoned to their mama; Eliza was putting on her bonnet and warm garden-coat to go and feed her poultry, an occupation of which she was fond: and not less **so** of selling the eggs to the housekeeper and hoarding up the money she thus obtained.
>   (Jane Eyre)

What does *so* indicate? What's the part of speech of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an adverb meaning ‘to that extent; in that degree’. It is used here to show that she was just as fond of selling the eggs as she was of feeding the poultry.

Comment: If 'so' is an adjective and indicate 'fond,' I can understand easy why 'so' followed by preposition 'of.': even if 'so' is an adverb, it can be followed by 'of'?

Comment: *Fond* is retrievable from the previous clause. Since *fond* has to be followed by *of* in this context, *of* is needed before *selling*.

Comment: Now i understand why you say the word, adverb. Thank you very much.